# Remove special repository

Tags: directory, google-drive, removing

In trying to install `googledrive` repository with `google-drive-ocamlfuse`, I got stuck with this error:

```
cannot access 'googledrive': Transport endpoint is not connected
```

I can't remove `googledrive` (originally a directory) with `rm -rf googledrive`. How can I remove it another way?

With the command `apt-cache policy google-drive-ocamlfuse`, I have

```
google-drive-ocamlfuse:
  Installed: 0.7.26-0ubuntu1~ubuntu20.04.1
  Candidate: 0.7.26-0ubuntu1~ubuntu20.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.7.26-0ubuntu1~ubuntu20.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alessandro-strada/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**EDIT**

```
┌─╼ [~]
└╼ mount | grep -F googledrive
google-drive-ocamlfuse on /home/maxime/googledrive type fuse.google-drive-ocamlfuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy google-drive-ocamlfuse` ? Do you want remove the application too, or only its data?

Comment: @N0rbert No, I just want to remove the directory related to `googledrive`. So I want to remove the data. I will add some details in the question.

Comment: please add output of `mount | grep -F googledrive` to your question.

Comment: @pLumo I added the output in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sudo umount /home/maxime/googledrive
```

and if it does not work (e.g. *"target busy"*) or takes a long time (cancel with ctrl+c):

```
sudo umount -l /home/maxime/googledrive
```

> `-l, --lazy`
> Lazy unmount.  Detach the filesystem from the file hierarchy now,
> and clean up all references to this filesystem as soon as it is not busy anymore.
> [...] The recommended use-case for umount -l is to prevent hangs on shutdown due to an unreachable network share where a normal  umount will hang due to a downed server or a network partition.

Then you can remove the directory:

```
rmdir /home/maxime/googledrive
```